# Gala type of game list of missile and list of asteroid collisions

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem intersecting these two list using Rectangle.Intersect.
i tried putting for loop inside the missile or asteroid but it has an error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < missile.Count; i++)
{
    missile[i].setMissileY();
    if (rect_Light.Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle()))
    {
       missile.Remove(missile[i]);
    }
} 

for (int i = 0; i < asteroid.Count; i++)
{
    asteroid[i].setAsteroidY();
    if (asteroid[i].getAsteroidY() >= Window.ClientBounds.Height || rect_Player.Intersects(asteroid[i].getAsteroidRectangle()))
    {
       if (rect_Player.Intersects(asteroid[i].getAsteroidRectangle()))
       {
          life -= 1;
       }
       asteroid[i].asteroidRectangle.X = asteroidPos.Next(Window.ClientBounds.Width - 60);
       asteroid[i].asteroidRectangle.Y = asteroidPos.Next(-800, -57);
    }
}
```

when i add this line of code inside the forloop with missile.count

```
foreach (AsteroidClass ac in asteroid)
{
    if (ac.getAsteroidRectangle().Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle()))
    {
       missile.Remove(missile[i]);
       ac.asteroidRectangle.X = asteroidPos.Next(Window.ClientBounds.Width - 60);
       ac.asteroidRectangle.Y = asteroidPos.Next(-800, -57);
    }
}
```

it returns an error when my missle hits an asteroid
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving.

Comment: @Adrian here it is. I really dont know the logic for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that the completed code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < missile.Count; i++)
{
    missile[i].setMissileY();
    if (rect_Light.Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle()))
    {
       missile.Remove(missile[i]);
    }

    foreach (AsteroidClass ac in asteroid)
    {
        if (ac.getAsteroidRectangle().Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle())) // Error here
        {
            missile.Remove(missile[i]); // Or pehaps error here
            ac.asteroidRectangle.X = asteroidPos.Next(Window.ClientBounds.Width - 60);
            ac.asteroidRectangle.Y = asteroidPos.Next(-800, -57);
        }
    }
```

}

In which case this will result in a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the current `missile[i]`  was already removed from the collection from the intersection with `rect_Light`.

You need at add a `continue` statement after the missile has been removed to prevent the asteriod collision check from being executed if the missile no longer exists. e.g.

```
if (rect_Light.Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle()))
{
    missile.Remove(missile[i]);
    continue; // this will cause the foreach loop to iterate straight to the next missile without doing the asteroid check.
}
```

This will move the for loop on to the next missile.

Similarly, you will need to do something similar to the asteroid collision check. A `break` statement would be required instead however since you need to leave the foreach loop.

```
 foreach (AsteroidClass ac in asteroid)
 {
    if (ac.getAsteroidRectangle().Intersects(missile[i].getMissileRectangle())) // Error here
    {
        missile.Remove(missile[i]); // Or pehaps error here
        ac.asteroidRectangle.X = asteroidPos.Next(Window.ClientBounds.Width - 60);
        ac.asteroidRectangle.Y = asteroidPos.Next(-800, -57);
        break; // this will exit the foreach loop for asteroid.
    }
 }
```